# non lazy ptr linking error - the solution

Tags: iphone, xcode, non-lazy-ptr

I have received many errors while trying to Build & Run my iphone app using the xcode.
All the errors stated "**non lazy ptr**" for the used variables in the code.
The solution for me (and for all of you) is to look for the correct framework to be used according to the Simulator and Device versions the code will be running on.
At first i have chosen the AVFoundation framework from the iphone os 2.2 folder. and when i removed that and choose the framework from the iphone os 3.0 folder - the linking errors where gone and the code run perfectly.
so, in short the solution is to **change the framework source folder**.
Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Frameworks should automatically be taken from the Active SDK, so resetting them shouldn't be necessary.  We've seen some projects that have somehow gotten hardcoded SDK paths into their Framework Search Paths build settings; that is often the cause of this problem (and your fix simply hardcodes a more-recent path for an invalid one, which kicks the can down the road a ways but will break again in the next SDK bump.)  The real solution is to look at your target's Framework Search Paths and delete any SDK-specific paths you find.